# Create a data model by third person without affecting the database

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, data-modeling, datamodel

If I have database that has about 100 tables and I cannot create a database diagram in the SQL server 2008 R2 due to circumstances.

Is there a third person (application) that can create a database data model by reading the database and its content?

The goal is to create a data model without affecting the content of the database.
I need to view what datatype, primary and secondary key, constraint etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a license, you can use Microsoft Visio to generate an ERD from an existing database.

If not, you could give [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/) a try.

---

EDIT:

[Please check this article for information on how to use the ERD functionality in Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio-help/create-a-database-model-also-known-as-entity-relationship-diagram-HA010357092.aspx).

Comment: Where can I find that functionality in Visio? Is it enough to use Visio 2010

Answer (score 0):

[Microsoft Visio](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/visio/) and [CA ERwin](http://erwin.com/products/detail/ca_erwin_data_modeler_standard_edition/) are two that I've used in the past.